# inline-block not laying out horizontally like they should be

Tags: css, html

The blocks are being laid out vertically (one on top of the other), I'm trying to use inline blocks to place 2 blocks side by side. I wanted to use inline-block instead of floats which do work. The steps div class is the container for both inline blocks. Am I missing something?

```css
img.down_image {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 465px;
}
div.steps {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 500px;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
ol {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0 0 0 40px;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  counter-reset: numList;
  font: 16px sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
the html:

<div class="steps">
  <div class="down_image">
    <img src="pic1.png" class="down_image" />
  </div>
  <ol>
    <li>sdsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdg</li>
    <li>sdgsdgsdgsdgsdg <a href="https://java.com/en/download/" class="link">install Java.</a>
    </li>
    <li>sdgsdgsdgsdgsdg</li>
  </ol>

</div>
```

Comment: Post your HTML please. And why do you have `display: block;` in `div.steps`?

Comment: @j08691 because I position that container like block elements, also added in the html

Comment: @jacksexton, `div` by itself `is` a `block` element. `display: block;` is redundant for it

Comment: @ankhzet did not know that, thanks for clarifying

Comment: @jacksexton "I'm trying to use inline blocks to place 2 blocks side by side" - what are the two inline blocks you mentioned there? Are you talking about [1] the image and [2] the list ?

Comment: @ArghyaC yes those are the two elements I need side by side, before I was using float left and right but I thought using inlineblock would be better

Comment: And the `li` elements will be blocks right?

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen I have not added styling to it so I assume they are blocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following in your style

```
div.down_image {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You made the image inline, but the container div is not inline!
If you still have same issue, check the widths! Total width of 400 (ol) + 465 (img) = 865px might be more than the area you are using.

This code works fine, when widths are fixed. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fksm4z35/4/#update)

Comment: I assume that is part of the problem but that did not fix it :(

Comment: @jacksexton the code in the answer seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/317/

Comment: @ArghyaC looks like its always best to specify a width... lesson learned. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add `white-space: nowrap;` to `div.steps` and change html:

```css
    div.down_image {
      width: 60%;
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #ded;
    }
    div.steps {
      white-space: nowrap;
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      height: 500px;
      top: 50%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    ol {
      background-color: #dde;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 30%;
      height: auto;
      padding: 0 0 0 5%;
      list-style: none;
      overflow: hidden;
      counter-reset: numList;
      font: 16px sans-serif;
      color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<div class="steps">
    <div class="down_image">
        &nbsp;
    </div><ol>
        <li> sdsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdg</li>
        <li> sdgsdgsdgsdgsdg <a href="https://java.com/en/download/" class="link">install Java.</a></li>
        <li> sdgsdgsdgsdgsdg</li>
    </ol>

</div>
```

*Notice glued `</div><ol>`*

***Note: make sure to add `div.down_image { display: inline-block; }`***

Also, you can try to give `position: absolute;` to image's `div` and `ol`.

Comment: didn't change anything either.

Comment: @jacksexton, you forgot to make a `div.down_image` inlined block?